# Add Custom Headers for request in dofilter at Gateway level

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-zuul, api-gateway

I'm  implementing api gateway where bases on the request uri. I need to add additional headers in `chain.doFilter(request,response)`.

my filter is jwt filter as following

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        CustomHttpServletRequest cRequest = new CustomHttpServletRequest(request);

        /* authenticate user for valid token if valid then add the following header*/

        if(request.getRequestURI().equals("/testService/updateHeader")) {
              cRequest.putHeader("test","Test-header");
        }


        filterChain.doFilter(cRequest, response);
    }
}
```

implemented based on [reference](https://wilddiary.com/adding-custom-headers-java-httpservletrequest/):

and in my testservice and trying to fetch header in the headers i am not able to get the header name

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that in filterChain.doFilter(request, response) you use original request, but not new one with custom heeader. Change

```
filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
```

to

```
filterChain.doFilter(cRequest, response);
```

Comment: i am passing cRequest forgot to mention in the question

Comment: Where is your "testservice"? Does it come after this filter in filterchain?

Comment: testservice is another microservice with is running on different port then the route is 
/testService/** will reroute to testservice instance 
which comes above mentioned code will be in between the client and service each request and response this will do.

Comment: This request is processed inside application of this Filter. If you another service processed response of first application, then you need to add header to the response of first app which is the request for the second app.

Comment: when the request hits with gateway port and gateway will route the request to that service(application). it will go through above filter process the request then route to the another service(application).

Comment: [see here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OPSYRCPQFTv6OmvHCzIa3AOGNe0_mD-I/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you provide source code where request passes to the service?